# Hierarchically numbering nested orders lists in css?

Tags: jquery, html, css

If you have a standard ordered list in HTML like:

```
<ol>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <ol>
       <li>Third</li>
       <li>Fourth</li>
       <ol>
           <li>Fifth</li>
           <li>Sixth</li>
       </ol>
   </ol>
   <li>Seventh</li>
</ol>
```

Is it possible without adding any HTML tags to style lists like these in CSS or JQuery that it automatically appears like:

```
A. First
B. Second
     I. Third
     II. Fourth
         1. Fifth
         2. Sixth
C. Seventh
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
ol {list-style-type: upper-alpha}
ol ol {list-style-type: upper-latin}
ol ol ol {list-style-type: decimal}
```

Then, never ever suggest using jQuery for basic styling again...